# Replace (every) element in a list by the median of the nearest neighbors

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, median

I have an array `A`, say :

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

And I wish to create a new array `B` by replacing each element in `A` by the median of its four nearest neighbors, **without** taking into account the value at the given position... for example :

```
B[2] = np.median([A[0], A[1], A[3], A[4]]) (=3)
```

The thing is that I need to perform this on a gigantic `A` and I want to optimize times, so I want to avoid for loops or similar. And... I don't care about the result at the edges.

I already tried `scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter` but it is not producing the desired output :

```
import scipy.ndimage
B = scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter(A,footprint=[1,1,0,1,1],mode='wrap')
```

which produces `B=[7,4,4,5,6,7,6,6]`, which is clearly not the correct answer. 
Any idea is welcome.

Comment: How are you calculating the 4 nearest neighbors? Are the values distinct? This is a fairly straightforward problem and can be accomplished in `O(n lg n)`

Comment: Sounds like a kernel operation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html  -  or something you want to do after/with fourier transform/multiply/reverse fourier on images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way could be using `np.roll` to shift the number in your array such as:

```
A_1 = np.roll(A,1)
# output: array([8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

And then the same thing with rolling by -2, -1 and 2:

```
A_2 = np.roll(A,2)
A_m1 = np.roll(A,-1)
A_m2 = np.roll(A,-2)
```

Now you just need to sum your 4 arrays, as for each index you have the 4 neighbors in one of them:

```
B = (A_1 + A_2 + A_m1 + A_m2)/4.
```

And as you said you don't care about the edges, I think it works for you!

EDIT: I guess I was focus on the rolling idea that I mixed up mean and median, the median can be calculated by `B = np.median([A_1,A_2,A_m1,A_m2],axis=0)`

Comment: That's the mean.

Comment: For the median you would have to stack these four arrays and then calculate the median along the right axis.

Comment: Median would be taking the array of values, giving them all appropriate array numbers, and finding center values. Example: Array[0] being the smallest value, Array[4] being the largest, would leave Array[2] as the median.

Comment: Indeed, then doing `np.median([A_1,A_2,A_m1,A_m2],axis=0)` is the median value?

Comment: Yeah. It's the mean but it was close!! The correct way would be:
B = np.median([np.roll(A,-2),np.roll(A,-1),np.roll(A,1),np.roll(A,2)],axis=0)
Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a rolling, central window of length 5 in pandas, and apply the median function to the values of the window, the middle one masked away:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

mask = np.array(np.ones(5), bool)
mask[5//2] = False

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(A)

r5 = df.rolling(5, center=True)

result = r5.apply(lambda x: np.median(x[mask]))

result
     0
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  3.0
3  4.0
4  5.0
5  6.0
6  NaN
7  NaN
```

Comment: Oh my... completely right. I'll edit it to meet the asked problem right.